# Version control system and front end interface for 40+ students

Tags: linux, version-control

I am looking for a version control system that will allow me to create any number of repositories and allow up to 30+ people to be able to access it as cheaply as possible. We can host this ourselves and backup to another server.

I have used Bitbucket for my own personal things, but I know, if I want more than 5 people they start charging.

We are going to be using this on a Linux system (Ubuntu/Mint) with people who may not have used Linux before. 
A front end GUI like Source Tree would be great.

If it's best just to use the command line then so be it (it should only make them better).

Stability, ease of use and longevity are important.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! And congrats for finding the correct tag :) Next step: Click the tag. Your answers wait for you [behind it](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-control). I personally recommend Git; you can find a "starter's collection" to it in [my Gist](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/) (direct link: [Git Resources.md](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/85627ffcb1ac4b24c9b1)). Good luck, and enjoy!

Comment: if you don't need to keep the repos private using [github](https://github.com/) is free and gives the students another thing to put on their resumes

Comment: I did think about that. They are going to be creating simple websites with something like WordPress to get them started and the whole idea is to give them the experiencing and portfolio for to get their first major jobs.  

I thinking that should be quick for them to see results and a good anchor to give them a reason to learn more about how its made. 

I guess as long as they are simple information sites without the need for log ons and e-commerce keeping it public shouldn't matter to much.

Comment: Sorry, there is an implication. When crating WordPress sites the database info is kepted in a config file. How would I manage this? Otherwise anyone could access the database of any website they made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very popular version control system these days is *[Git](http://git-scm.com/)*.

*[GitHub](https://github.com/pricing)* is free with unlimited collaborators for public repositories. If you need private repositories take a look at [*GitLab*](https://about.gitlab.com/); it's free when you host it yourself. If you're looking for a basic Git server take a look at *[Gitolite](http://gitolite.com)*.

The *[Git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools)* offers an overview of graphical and web interfaces that are available. A good Git GUI for Linux is [*SmartGit*](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) (free for non-commercial use).

Comment: @Chop: SourceTree is not available for Linux at the moment. But you reminded me of Gitolite and I improved my answer.

Comment: Smart Git seems really odd. I downloaded it but you are not allowed to use it for anything remotely to do with business or profit :(

Answer (score 1):

For SCM newbies, [PlasticSCM](https://www.plasticscm.com/home.html) probably has the best GUI out there.

It also has one of the bedt diff & merge systems.

Take a look at [the gallery](https://www.plasticscm.com/gallery.html) and read about [the features](https://www.plasticscm.com/features/index.html).

One big plus for sCM newbies is that you can configure it so you don't need to check out. Just start editing, creating, renaming 7 deleting files & PlasticSCM will track it all (of course, you do need to check in ;-)).

I have been using it for years and it is my SCM of choice.

Comment: I agree it does look really nice. But it seems rather expensive with a monthly/yearly subscription. I will have to run this past my partner.Thank you though this is one option I have never seen before

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that. I use the free personal version (I think it used to be up to 5 developers). It is free for non-profit organizations and Open Source - are you a non-profit? They also have educational discounts. I have found them to be very helpful; why not email them, tell them what you are up to and ask them what they recommend? You might get a happy surprise :-)  Btw, if you try it & write them a sort of review of your impressions (which they use to improve the product), they will send you a free T-shirt :-)